# Android - Animate views that are programatically added to the layout

Tags: android, android-animation

I am creating a couple of TextViews programmatically and adding to a Linear Layout.Everything works fine.

Now I want to add some animations on the TextViews. After adding the textviews I am trying to add animations on them using the ViewPropertyAnimator. But I don't see any animations. If I add them in the xml for testing, it works fine.

I found some thing like we need to add an event for when the textview is attached to the screen and code the animation here. But I have a set of animations to be run on each TextView and after it is done I need to start animations on the other.

Any ideas or pointers how I can achieve this?

My code is some thing like,

-- Create the TextViews(invisible) in a loop and  add them to the layout.
-- After the above step trying to animate like below each of the text views one by one. I need to chain as I need to fade in one by one.

```
        tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tv1.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(500);
```

But the animations are not working.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

The `ViewPropertyAnimator` animates properties from their current value to a specified value. Since the alpha of newly instantiated Views is 1, your animation will animate alpha from 1 to 1. You should first set the alpha to 0 rather than setting the visibility:

```
tv1.setAlpha(0);
tv1.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(500);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good info for me related to ViewPropertyAnimator. See my other comment.

Comment: If you use `animateLayoutChanges`, you don't need to have a separate animation handler. The system will handle the animations for you. You might need a handler in order to stagger the adding of the views so that the animations are staggered.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your containing viewgroup `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` and take a look at the `LayoutTransition` class here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.html

Comment: I added the property in XML and set the LayoutTransition but still no luck. After adding something like below after adding views and before starting the animations, I can see the animations.        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                animateDropContainers();
            }
        }, 2000);

Comment: It is because when you set that attribute to true, android will perform the amimations for you when your views are added or removed, you dont have to do anything BY DEFAULT